How to sort list of completions produced by eglot and company-mode?
I have eglot, company-mode, LSP (phpactor). It's working but list of completions is not sorted by string length which makes it almost unusable.
Is there any way to sort list of completions from shortest to longest string?

There is a user option company-transformers which allows you to choose from existing sorting functions, or set up your own.
No built-in option to "sort by string length", but it seems easy enough to implement in custom Lisp.

The small library sortie.el (code) is very general.
It's specifically for sorting completion candidates, on the fly, that is, interactively. The candidates can be of any kind, and you can sort them any way you like (in any sort order).
